# How to include strings and variables in the file path for read.csv in R?

Tags: r, string, csv, variables, filepath

I am trying to enter a file path into a function where part of the function reads data from .csv files from a folder specified in the function.

This part of the script:

```
prep_data <- function("filepath", Year_First, Year_Last)  {
...
FileName <- paste0(filepath,"/details", Year_Index, "moredetails", Year_Index, ".csv")
Tbl_Year <- read.csv(FileName)
```

Where

```
prep_data("/users/me/etc", 1980, 2014)
```

Is giving me this error:

```
In file(file, "rt") :
cannot open file 'filepath/details1980moredetails1980.csv': No such file or directory
```

My desired file path would be:

```
/users/me/etc/details1980moredetails1980.csv
```

This line is in a for loop that is reading .csv files for the range of specified years.

Comment: It should be `prep_data <- function(filepath, Year_First, Year_Last)` with `filepath` unquoted.  But I don't even see how that works without error

Comment: Thanks @RichardScriven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
read.csv(paste0(getwd(),'/details/, Year_Index, 'moredetails', Year_Index, '.csv'),header=TRUE,sep=',',FactorAsString=TRUE)
```

Suggest try getwd() for filepath if your files saved in directory.