# How to read in file with dynamic name while avoiding hard-coding in R?

Tags: r, filepath, read.csv, hardcoded

I run into issues reading in csv files with dynamic names **and** avoiding hard coding the file path. I'd like short tidy code (non-hardcoded). If I hardcode the full path (everything before the "~") it reads in the files fine. But soft-coding (if that is the opposite of hard coding) the file path it gives the error (despite showing the correct path in the error. I have two variable parts of the file name that I paste into the file name before reading it in. If I avoid paste and just type a path per individual it also works.

```
#dynamic part I usually have in a loop with all the options. 
part_a <- "outside" #other options here in my loop include "inside"
part_b <- "late" # other option "early" or "preterm"

#reading in the df
df <-read.csv(paste0("~/Data/FromR/clean_",part_a,part_b,"_2016.csv"),
                           check.names=FALSE, na.strings="null")

Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
    In addition: Warning message:
    In file(file, "rt") :
      cannot open file 'C:/Users/myname/Documents/Data/FromR/clean_outsidelate_2016.csv': No such file or directory
```

if I use `getwd()` in the first part of the paste in place of `~` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249433/how-to-include-strings-and-variables-in-the-file-path-for-read-csv-in-r) it works by producing this string `"C:/Users/myname/Documents/MyR_Projects/Specific_R_project/"` at the beginning of the paste. But how can I get it to work with the "~"? when using the `~` it stops at the "Documents" folder...

The desired outcome is to read in the file without error perform functions and repeat with other files. My loop works fine hardcoded, and I only wanted to make it more general or softcoded.

Comment: Please include expected output. Are you trying to read in two files?

Comment: what does `getwd()` return?

Comment: I updated the question. Right now the issue to be solved involves a single file to read in.  `getwd()` returns everything in the working directory path as I corrected in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to read a file (`testFile.txt`) in my home from a different `wd`and it works fine with `~`

```
 myFile <- "testFile
 mymy <- ".txt"
 ciao <- read.delim(paste0("~/",myFile,mymy))
```

In powershell you can use `%~%` (have a look here [tread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228950/what-is-the-alternative-for-users-home-directory-on-windows-command-prompt)), but I am not sure how to expand the `$HOME` in R.

```
#-------- edit
```

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460556/how-to-reset-path-expand-on-tilde) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016907/setting-the-home-directory-in-windows-r). Basically any variable defined in your `.Renviron` should be accessible.

Comment: Fixed my question to have correct file name. What resources are there for checking how a single character symbols are treated such as `~`?